# C# - System.FormatException SQLite connection

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am experiencing an error that I cannot understand, can anyone explain to me what I am miserably doing wrong?

Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "posti_auto_mil" (
    "n_posto"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "id_utente" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "targa_1"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "targa_2"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "targa_3"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "targa_4"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "targa_5"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "locazione" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

LoadCar.cs

```
public static bool CheckTarga(int idUtente)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                var output = cnn.Query($"select * from utenti where id = {idUtente}").FirstOrDefault();

                if (output != null)
                {
                    var targa = cnn.Query($"select * from posti_auto_mil where id = {idUtente}").FirstOrDefault();

                    if (targa != null)
                    {
                        var checkpresenza = cnn.Query($"select locazione from posti_auto_mil where id_utente = {idUtente} limit 1");

                        if (checkpresenza.ToString() == "interno")
                        {
                            targaicon = 1;
                        }
                        else if (checkpresenza.ToString() == "esterno")
                        {
                            targaicon = 2;
                        }
                        else if (checkpresenza.ToString() == "provvisorio")
                        {
                            targaicon = 2;
                        }
                        else targaicon = 3;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    targaicon = 3;
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Form1.cs

```
//Parking
                //Visibilità
                listView_targheinfo.Items.Clear();
                listView_targheinfo.Visible = true;
                pictureBox_infobox.Visible = true;


                if (Classi.LoadCar.CheckTarga(Int32.Parse(home_textBox_id.Text)) == true)
                {
                    if (Classi.LoadCar.targaicon == 1)
                    {
                        pictureBox_infobox.BackgroundImage = global::RegistroAccessi_8Rgt.Properties.Resources.parking_32px_green;
                    }
                    else if (Classi.LoadCar.targaicon == 2)
                    {
                        pictureBox_infobox.BackgroundImage = global::RegistroAccessi_8Rgt.Properties.Resources.no_parking_32px;
                    }
                    else if (Classi.LoadCar.targaicon == 3)
                    {
                        pictureBox_infobox.BackgroundImage = global::RegistroAccessi_8Rgt.Properties.Resources.parking_32px_yellow;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox_infobox.BackgroundImage = global::RegistroAccessi_8Rgt.Properties.Resources.no_parking_32px;
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    pictureBox_infobox.BackgroundImage = global::RegistroAccessi_8Rgt.Properties.Resources.no_parking_32px;
                }
```

**Error:**

[image: Error Screen]

I've done various tests but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... can someone clarify this for me?

I can do a personnel search in the same way but I can't do it for vehicle number plates.

Comment: Don't construct SQL strings by concatenating input. This leaves the code wide open to SQL injection and formatting problems. It's actually easier to write parameterized queries, *especially* when you seem to be using Dapper. You can get rid of all the calls to `ToString()` by specifying the result type with eg `Query<string>`

Comment: It seems you could get rid of most of the code if you actually returned the `locazione` value and mapped it to a resource using a dictionary